# Aliasing ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have association:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end
```

I'd like to change the name of this association with keeping backward compatibility and information about the deprecation. So something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :new_bars, class_name: 'Bar'

  # some alias to the old association
  # def bars
  #    # Deprecation warning
  #    new_bars
  # end
```

How to alias the association and ensure that it will be compatible with all ActiveRecord features as it was before change.

Comment: Leave the old 'has_many' in there? Granted it won't give a deprecation warning...

Comment: Bear in mind that if you do this without the Big Giant Refactor you want to avoid, you may get issues if different parts of the code try to access it under different names. If you just alias the method, you may lose some functionality around any code that uses association reflection - Active Record joins for example, or some gems.

Comment: I would just do a complete refactor and be done, assuming there isn't a legacy system involved that you don't have control over.

Comment: How do you think why I'm trying thes hack ? :D It's big and nasty legacy system

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do what you require is:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :new_bars, class_name: 'Bar'

  # Overwrite legacy association with alias to the new association:
  def bars
     #If you're using Airbrake:
     #Airbrake.notify(Exception.new("Deprecation: bars association called on Foo"))
     logger.warn "Deprecation: bars association called on Foo"
     new_bars
  end
end
```

You want operations that require Active Record reflection to work with both associations (so joins/includes will still work for example), so you need both associations defined. However, you want explicit calls either association to return the same thing, so you need the alias method as well. Otherwise, one method could update one association followed by another method that reads the other. Then things will get really weird.

I haven't tested this, so please make sure you create some sensible unit tests before putting it into production. And if you possibly, possibly, possibly can, refactor the whole code-base. These kind of hacks WILL bite you in the proverbial at some point in future.